# Get SQL Select progress like SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

Is it possible to receive SELECT or Procedure Execution progress from SQL Database using .Net framework?
Whenever you select big data in SSMS, it shows you progress of execution, I mean it gives you +=500 - 500 rows. Can I make same in my WinForm project?

Comment: What tools do you use for executing queries? SqlCommand or Entity Framework?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do that with ADO.NET/SQL Server. You can simply hook up an event to `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler` like this:

```
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(“................”);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(ProgressStatus);

    // Execute your long running query here
}

private void ProgressStatus(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.Errors.Count > 0)
   {
       string message = e.Errors[0].Message;
       int state = e.Errors[0].State;
       // Set status of the progress bar
       // progressBar1.Value = state;
   }
}
```

And in your SQL statement/stored procedure if you have multiple statements to execute, you might choose to report the status of those statements i.e.

```
SELECT ............ FROM .......... INNER JOIN ............. INNER JOIN ............
RAISERROR('Message',10,25) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT ............ FROM .......... INNER JOIN ............. INNER JOIN ............
RAISERROR('Message',10,50) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT ............ FROM .......... INNER JOIN ............. INNER JOIN ............
RAISERROR('Message',10,75) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT ............ FROM .......... INNER JOIN ............. INNER JOIN ............
RAISERROR('Message',10,100) WITH NOWAIT
```

`NOWAIT` option will force the message to be delivered to the client immediately instead of waiting until everything is done.

BTW maybe I misunderstood the question, and you need to paginate results and report progress on pages, then you will need a different answer.